# How do I collapse all bookmarks in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF with lots of bookmarks that are all expanded every time I open it. Is there an easy way to collapse the bookmarks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Collapse all bookmarks**

1. Select a bookmark
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Num /</kbd> - That's the <kbd>/</kbd> on the number pad, not the one next to the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

**Collapse/Expand a bookmark and all its sub-bookmarks**

1. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the expand/collapse icon (+/-) next to the bookmark.

**Collapse a bookmark and all its sub-bookmarks**

1. Select the bookmark you want to collapse
2. Press <kbd>/</kbd> - Either one will work for this, unlike collapsing all.

---

Note: Modifying the expanded/collapsed state of the bookmarks won't prompt you to save the PDF, so if that is all you changed and you want to save those changes you will need to select "Save As..." and save it back to its original location (overwrite the existing PDF).

Comment: Anyone know a way to do this for Mac users lacking a numeric keypad? Leave it to the bureaucrats at Adobe to make a shortcut for an optional key and provide no way to change your keyboard shortcuts.